# What does the H on Wrecking Ball's Wooden Ball skin stand for?

Tags: overwatch

There is a *H* inside what looks like a jigsaw piece on the front of Wrecking Ball's Wooden Ball skin.

Does anyone know what that stands for?

I don't see that *H* on his other skins.

[image: The Wooden Ball skin]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It most likely stands for Hammond, the hamster's name.